# simulate a button click on a datacard in Solidworks PDM AddIn

Tags: solidworks, solidworksapi, solidworkspdmapi

I have a Solidworks PDM AddIn that listens for a button click on a datacard to perform a specific action. I cannot change this AddIn or view the code.
Now I want to use a second PDM AddIn, do some actions and then trigger the first AddIn witout clicking the button on the datacard.

I was searching the Solidworks PDM API Documentation for any help about doing a button click on a datacard but cannot find anything. Is this possible? Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: I don't see a way to trigger a command via the data card in the API help. If it were there, I imagine it would be in either the IEdmCardControl or IEdmVault interfaces and there's nothing there, unfortunately.

Comment: @bigcrazyal There is a getbuttoncommand method to get a command string that is executed when a button is clicked. Is there a way to run this command? [link] (https://help.solidworks.com/2023/english/api/epdmapi/epdm.interop.epdm~epdm.interop.epdm.iedmcardcontrol5~getbuttoncommand.html)

Comment: I'd ask a question like this on cadoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

PDM Add-ins are stored locally in the client cache and can be retrieved and reversed engineering using a tool like dotpeek. Make sure you have the rights to the code before you attempt this...

I don't think you can trigger the OnCmd method of another add-in. Only the PDM client can do that.